# Making AJAX Call For Use In Multiple Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to make numerous AJAX calls and want to set up a simple method to handle this. I created the following

```
function testingAjax(url) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: url,
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(data);
      return data;
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert('error')
    }
  });
};
```

When I call `testingAjax` from another method, I get an `Undefined` error, yet when I alert from within `testingAjax` it is correct.

```
function testingCall(){
    var data = testingAjax(url);
    alert(data);
}
```

Basically, I want to return the data from the AJAX call, and parse it elsewhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This general question has been asked hundreds of times (it is a common point of learning).  The Ajax call is asynchronous.  Your function returns long before the ajax call is done.  As such, you cannot return the value directly.  You must use promises or callbacks.  See the question yours has been marked a dup of for many possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure what to even search on and figured someone would post some hints at what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add a callback param (which is a function) and pass it to success in place of what you already have.

```
function testingAjax(url, cb) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: url,
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: cb,    
    error: function(err) {
      alert('error')
    }
  });
};
```

To use it:

```
testingAjax('myurl', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

This will take the value of the success callback and immediately pass it as an argument to your custom callback, which will allow you access to `data`.

Comment: Thanks Seth, appreciate the helpful response! I understand much better now.